# Pattern Matcher replaceAll

Tags: java, android, regex

I simply trying (in vain) to remove all instances of the word 'at' during a loop.

```
Pattern atPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\bat\\b.*");
String input = "at Pat's attic a fat cat catcher at patted at"

// required output "Pat's attic a fat cat catcher patted"

output = input.replace(atPattern.pattern(), " ");

output= input.replaceAll(".*\\bat\\b.*", " ");

Matcher atMatcher = atPattern.matcher(input);

output = atMatcher.replaceAll(" ");

// Starting to clutch at straws now...

Matcher atMatcher = Pattern.compile(".*\\bat\\b.*").matcher(input);

output = atMatcher.matcher(input).replaceAll(" ");

output = atPattern.matcher(input).replaceAll(" ");
```

I've tried many other combinations of the above too, but I just cannot get the output I want...

Please can you put me out of my misery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `replaceAll(...)` is sufficient, and you'll need to remove some optional spaces after such `at`'s:

```
String input = "at Pat's attic a fat cat catcher at patted at";
String expected = "Pat's attic a fat cat catcher patted";

System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\bat\\b\\s*", "").trim());
System.out.println(expected.trim());
```

The above will print:

```
Pat's attic a fat cat catcher patted
Pat's attic a fat cat catcher patted
```

Comment: There is actually a trailing space in the first line of your output

Comment: @nhahtdh, ah yes, a simple `trim()` will remedy that :)

Comment: This answer gives the correct results in all of my random strings. Thank you. I can use .trim() to clear any white space. I'll return and mark it as correct later, unless there's somehow a better response!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done simply by:

```
"at Pat's attic a fat cat catcher at patted at"
    .replaceAll("\\bat\\b","").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ")
```

The `trim()` and the second `replaceAll()` are for removing spaces.

There are probably other ways to do all of these in one step (possibly faster?), but separating them is easier to think about the logic.

**EDIT**

Just in case, this is one one-step solution:

```
.replaceAll("(?i)(\\bat\\b | ?\\bat\\b)","")
```

The `(?i)` is added for case-insensitivity. You can remove it if you don't need.

Comment: Thank you! Works great unless the String is "at at at" using .replaceAll("(\\bat\\b | \\bat\\b)","") it returns 'at'.

Comment: @andjav: Didn't think of this case. Post will be edited shortly.

Comment: Thanks. Bart Kiers' answer used s* . Your answer uses ? . Should the ideal answer use both do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
.replaceAll("(\\s|^)(at)(\\s|$)", " ").trim()
```

Comment: This time "at" in "attic" got eaten up.

Comment: Actually, OP's idea of using the word boundary `\b` is good, and it cleans up the "at" even if "at" has a comma/full stop right before/after.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it doesn't work if the string is "cat at at at cat" though.. It returns 'cat at cat'

Comment: @andjav Yes,I found it. I think nhahtdh's answer is the right way.

Comment: nhahtdh's answer fails on 'at at at' so it's looking like Bart Kiers may be the correct one.. Unless you think otherwise?